# c# multiple if conditions in same lane

Tags: c#, .net

I have a slight problem when working with c# and using IF statments with multiple conditions.

This is the most common occurance.

```
private void SomeFunction(string SomeString)
{

   if(SomeString != null && SomeString.Trim() != "")
   {
   }
}
```

In some languages like javascript if the first argument fails (SomeString != null) the second check wont be made. C# seems to check both arguments even if the first one fails and then the second one will throw an exception since you cannot use .Trim() on a null value.

Right now I am going over this by nesting my ifs which is messy work. Like this:

```
private void SomeFunction(string SomeString)
{

   if(SomeString != null)
   {
     if(SomeString.Trim() != "")
     {
      .....
     }
   }
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions or best practices on a better way to solve this?

Comment: Good rule of thumb: **go with whatever is easier to read an understand**. Personally, I prefer the first. C# will not check the second condition if the first one fails.

Comment: C# uses short-circuit evaluation, just like JavaScript. If `SomeString` is null, the next part of the expression will *not* be evaluated.

Comment: I just checked the first code snippet and actually *SomeString.Trim() != ""* never got evaluated if the first fails. I am surprised!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is **totally wrong**. When you use the conditional **AND** if the first condition is FALSE the second condition is never evaluated or executed. In the conditional **OR** if the first condition is TRUE the second one is never evaluated or executed.

In other words, if the compiler has enough info to determine the result of the expression it stops to consider the second part of the expression.

This is known as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

It is a basic programming principle for C derived languages but also for every other major language.

Comment: After further testing you are very much right and I am very much ashemed for rushing on and posting before further investigating beyond a few google searches that did not give me the right answers. Seems this was not my problem and reason for exceptions but something else after all.

Answer (score 4):

> C# seems to check both arguments even if the first one fails

That's **not true**, see [&& Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way:

```
private void SomeFunction(string SomeString)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SomeString))
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it really address the OP problem? He asked about && operand evaluation!

Comment: Yes, it really address the problem. The last sentence of the question:
_Does anybody have any suggestions or best practices on a better way to solve this?_
And my answer demonstrates a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Strictly speaking, OP wrote `SomeString.Trim() != ""` which intends to check for **emptiness** and not for **is-white-space**.

Comment: @haim770: No, if the string contains only whitespace, `Trim()` removes all whitespace and returns an empty string.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The code example is just an example for a general problem. This only solves the example not the general problem which was in fact the question.

Comment: @Dennis: I'm sorry. I thought the question described an issue which was specific for checking whether strings contains only whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeString))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeString))
```

similar to ProgramFOX prefer this if you insist on doing ".Trim()"